# How to store imageable_id and imageable_type in photos table Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have three tables in my database(users,cars and photos).

Users Table

[image]

Cars Table

[image]

Photos Table

[image]

My Models:

**User.php**

```
public function photo() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable');
}
public function cars() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Car', 'user_id');
}
```

**Car.php**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
public function photo() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Photo', 'imageable');
}
```

**Photo.php**

```
protected $path = '/storage/images/';

public function getFileAttribute($file) {

    return $this->path . $file;

}

public function imageable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

My **Controller@store:**

```
$input = $request->all();
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('storage/images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file' => $name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id; 
    }
    $user->cars()->create($input);
    return back();
```

Imageable_id and imageable_type aren't storing. Just NULL. Why? How to store it?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the relationship when you create the photo.

```php
$photo = Photo::create(['file' => $name]);
```

It should be:

```php
$photo = $user->photo()->create(['file' => $name]);
```

---

Also, `$user->cars()->create(...)` instead of `$user->cars->create(...)`

Comment: Now storing id and type but it image is not displaying in view. Image is related to user but I want to relate it to car.

Comment: In database ('imageable_type') is App\Models\User but photo which I sent is for App\Model\Car

Comment: Then create the car first, save it to a variable and do $car->photo()->create(...)

Comment: My imageable_id is always 1